# In Mancala, are you allowed to pick up and count your opponent's stones?

Tags: mancala

In Mancala, are you allowed to pick up and count the number of stones your opponent has if the cup is too small to be able to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "serious play" you are not allowed to touch or count any piles. If you touch one of your own piles you have committed to picking up and playing that pile. Touching your opponent's piles, or either players' score piles is forbidden.